# "pivoting" two tables together to generate a new table

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

So I have three table columns that I'm trying to pivot together, in separate locations. All three columns have been added to my data model.

Here's what I have, here's what I'm trying to do:

Table Column 1:
A
B
C

Table Column 2:
Jan
Feb
Mar

Table Column 3:
X
Y
Z

Desired end result:

-- Jan   Feb   Mar   X   Y   X
A
B
C

Yes yes, copy and paste would generate the table, Transpose would get it in, etc. However, what happens when the tables expand or contract? I'm hoping to make it so that the table will auto-expand or contract with it. Trying to use the pivot feature in Power Query simply pivots the entire row, and adds everything to the values, instead of just creating a row and a column and leaving the table blank.

Is there an easy way to do this without VBA? Is it possible to do this without VBA, and make it so that values entered into the table are preserved?

Comment: Your end result layout isn't clear to me. Can you add some data and show the resulting summarizatio to better illustrate what goes where? And are there any common fields i.e. keys with which to stitch the tables together? Or are you wanting a simple crossjoin giving every possible combination of the three tables?

Comment: I'm not looking for a crossjoin - I know how to make those. What I'm looking for is similar to a crossjoin, but in a grid format for my resulting data, not a column format. Also, that is all the data - I'm hoping for a nearly-blank table

Comment: Your layout still confuses me. Shouldn't XYZ be repeated for each of Jan, Feb, March? Can you mock up in Excel what you want, and paste a screenshot?

Comment: XYZ should NOT be repeated for Jan, Feb, Mar. They're a straight append to each other.

Comment: And the end result has to be a PivotTable?

Comment: A blank table would be preferable, which can then be manually filled out

Comment: Ah...I just noticed your PowerQuery tag...I missed that earlier and was thinking the question related to PivotTables.